# Changing lstlistoflistings title

Tags: listings, lyx, naming

I'm having difficulty getting the list-of-listings section to display the proper title, it simply says "Contents" no matter what sort of changes I make. Here is the command I put in the preamble at a suggestion:

[image: Relevant preamble portion]

here is where I include the list of listings

[image: list of listings code]

but here is the listings page title...

[image]

and if it's relevant here is the output of a sample listing in my document:

[image]

to input the listings I am using insert-->Program Listing. I've googled a bit and searched around here but couldn't find anyone with a similar problem.. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: An attempt at a minimum nonworking example.

I'll do my best to make this helpful, but as I assume that I'm simply using the package incorrectly I'm not sure if this example is properly called 'nonworking'

Screencap of example (here I have made no changes to the preamble, everything is defaults)

[image]

and its output:

[image]

Now when I add the suggested line to preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Matlab Code}
```

the output is identical.

Comment: Hi. Can you give a [minimal working or nonworking example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that exhibits this problem?

Comment: How about exporting the `.lyx` code to `.tex` and posting it on [PastBin](http://pastebin.com). That way community members could import it again and try to duplicate your problem.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, answering  my own question here. It appears that this has something to do with older versions of listings, I found others with similar issues on a German message board and they linked to the following page with a few workaround scripts:

http://www.komascript.de/node/477

I don't fully understand what's going on with the scripts, but for now I'm getting the correct title of the list of listings page.